# how do i create a copy of an anylogic file compatible with older version?

Tags: anylogic

I created a model with Anylogic 8.7.6 but i need to continue it on an older (professional ) version 7.0.2. I need that the old version reads and ,more important, allows me to modify it.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For versions that are not too far away from each other, you can simply change the alp headers by opening the `.alp` file with an editor:
[image]

HOWEVER: AL7 is radically different and you will not easily convert an AL8 model back to it. There were many structural changes between them. You might be better off to open both AL8 and AL7 on your machine and manually copy over model contents (excluding any new functionality of AL8 obviously) bit by bit, then trying to get it to work again.

Comment: Regarding manually,the model contains many blocks, so i want to try the first method.Could you explain the steps?Thanks

Comment: The first method is replacing the version code :) It will not work 100%, no need to try :/